# this.element is not accessing any data in the element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to dynamically find which element the user clicks on. When the user clicks on an element, I want to be able to access the data of the element. Here is my code:

JS:

```
  $('.elements').on('click', function(){

    var elementClicked =   $(this.element).attr('rel'); 

    alert(elementClicked);
    console.log(elementClicked);

});
```

The alert gives me a message of undefined.

html:

```
    <body>
    <div id="gameholder">
        <div id="title"></div>
        <div class = "elements">
        <div rel = " first" class="penguin1"></div>
        <div rel = " second" class="penguin2"></div>
        <div rel = " third" class="penguin3"></div>
        <div rel = " fourth" class="penguin4"></div>
        </br>
        <div rel = " fifth" class="penguin5"></div>
        <div rel = " sixth" class="penguin6"></div>
        <div rel = " seventh" class="penguin7"></div>
        <div rel = " eigth" class="penguin8"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `$(this).` without `element`? Also change your on click selector to `$('.elements div')` **Example:** https://jsfiddle.net/jweppm8t/

Comment: Yes I have but it gives me undefined as well.

Comment: Check the example jsfiddle I have provided. All is working fine for me.

Comment: After changing the click selector it works perfectly. Would have taken me hours to figure that one out. Thanks @NewToJS

Comment: Very welcome! Sometimes you can overthink simple changes and it makes things feel more complicated, this is why it's always good to have others review the problem :)

Comment: You should be able to do that using `this.style.backgroundColor` assuming it's just a color you want to apply, if it's an image then you can use `this.style.backgroundImage="url('ImageUrl.jpg')"` **Example:** https://jsfiddle.net/jweppm8t/1/

Comment: Sorry I removed my comment because I thought I had it figured out. I can change the image background manually but I rather want to change it dynamically. I have all the images stored in an array. Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: That depends how you want to relate the images to the elements clicked. Do you mean you have the same amount of images as elements? So the first image in the array should apply to the first element and the second image for the second element? Or do you just want the images to apply to the elements depending on the order those images are clicked? Maybe if you create a jsfiddle it will give me something to look at/ work with.

Comment: Not quite. I am making a memory game so I stored all the images in an array and then want to use a random function in the beginning to give all the elements their initial position, if that makes sense.

Comment: how do I create a JS fiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/herculesking/pp2aa7r8/#&togetherjs=2zoUFcJBzd

Comment: I posted the code to JS fiddle @NewToJS

Answer (score 0):

Simply instead of this.element use this